# Access personal accounts Onedrive with Azure AD Multi tenant

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant

I would like to create a daemon app on Azure that would allow to access multiple personal Microsoft accounts (not in same tenant). My idea: I create a multi tenant app in my tenant. Each user that authorizes access to his personal account, should give explicit consent.

I feel like it's possible when I read the doc but I'm not able to do it.
What I currently did:

1. Create a V2 Multi Tenant app in Azure AD
2. Give Graph API: Files.Read.All and User.Read access on App permissions

Then I'm not sure how I should ask for the consent of users ?
And then how can I get a token for a particular user to have daemon access ? (without explicitly having to ask again his consent)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is an interesting question. The documentation did not explicitly say that you can't use app permissions with personal accounts. So those might work. You'll need to construct a login URL for your app, there they can consent to your permissions. You can use the "consumers" endpoint to only allow personal accounts.

Comment: App permissions would of course work differently for a personal since they are all in the same organisation technically. If app permissions don't work, you'll have to use delegated permissions + refresh tokens to run your background work.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is not really clear out of the documentation of Microsoft as first it seems it's possible, I have the impression that it's not possible: Daemon applications can work only in Azure AD tenants. It wouldn't make sense to build a daemon application that attempts to manipulate Microsoft personal accounts. If you're a line-of-business (LOB) app developer, you'll create your daemon app in your tenant. If you're an ISV, you might want to create a multitenant daemon application. Each tenant admin will need to provide consent. (https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview)